# Re-use relationship in model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am having issues with laravel 4 that did not happen with 3.

In the Permissions_Role model I have this relationship set up.

```
/**
 * User Relationship
 *
 * @return User
 */
 public function user()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
 }
```

Now, I want to use it later in the model to get that user's username.  In laravel 3 this could be done with the following.

```
return ucword($this->user()->first()->username);
```

However, in four, it does not seem to return an object the same way and I can't seem to figure out the new syntax for it.  Below is what I am trying currently.

```
/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string
 */
 public function getUsernameAttribute()
 {
     return ucwords($this->user()->first()->username);
 }
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure Permissions_Role `belongsTo` User? Or `hasMany`?

Comment: Also can you post more of your models? It's difficult to understand which model is which

Comment: This was user error.  I apologize.

Comment: Also, if your user model is named `User` then you probably don't want to have a method named `user` or it will be treated as your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to write () anymore, its automaticly castet into a property

new: `$this->user->username` instead of `$this->user()->username`